# How to copy namespace and attributes of root node with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSL/XML and I need help with XSL transformation.

I have XML which starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice
  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../ws/Invoice.xsd"
  xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
  xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
  xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"
  xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
  xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
  <ext:UBLExtension>
    <cbc:ID>INVOICE1</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Name>InvoiceIssuePlaceData</cbc:Name>
    <ext:ExtensionAgencyURI>urn:invoice:hr:issueplace</ext:ExtensionAgencyURI>
    <ext:ExtensionContent>
      <ext:InvoiceIssuePlace>London</ext:InvoiceIssuePlace>
    </ext:ExtensionContent>
  </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:ID>01 1206-2406-568</cbc:ID>
</Invoice>
```

I want to create elements for all attributes, and to create element between <_> tags for the value of node which has attribute.

Here is the xsl...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
  xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
  xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
  xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
  xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"
  xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../ws/Invoice.xsd"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*[@*]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
     <xsl:if test="count(@*)>=count(node())">
      <_>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </_>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:if test="count(node())>count(@*)">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
     </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that this transformation doesn't transforms root node (Invoice) as I would need. I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
  <xsi:schemaLocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../ws/Invoice.xsd</xsi:schemaLocation>
```

No other attributes in Invoice and as new elements. Only xsi:schemaLocation, but with namespace defined on the level of that node.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: *I want to create elements for all attributes, and to create element between `<_>` tags for the value of node which has attribute.*. I don't understand. What attributes are you referring to?

Comment: all and every attribute in the source xml should be transformed to child element, except for root node, which should keep namespace attributes and create child elements for each attribute.

Comment: Your XML contains namespace declarations, but there are no attributes. Please show us what the expected output looks like.

Comment: This question should have been closed. It's out-dated and the problem is not clearly framed. Get rid of confusing wording. A simple how do I get from this XML to this XML using XSLT would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
 <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
  <_><xsl:value-of select="."/></_> 
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform your root node into ...

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2">
  <xsi:schemaLocation>
    <_ xmlns="">urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../ws/Invoice.xsd</_>
  </xsi:schemaLocation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally clear as to what the issue is, but I *think* it might be to do with template you are using to match elements with attributes present

```
<xsl:template match="*[@*]"> 
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
```

In particular, the **xsl:element** command will create a whole new element, but you are not saying anything about what namespaces should be declared for that new element. Try this instead

```
<xsl:template match="*[@*]"> 
    <xsl:copy>
```

This should create a copy of the **Invoice** along with the namespace declarations (but its attributes).